# Is being a film director or a script writer for fictional and romantic stories against Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, work, profession

Is being a film director or a script writer for fictional and romantic stories against Islam?

Comment: Neither concepts of fiction nor romance are against Islam.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it doesn't lead or promote ideas, thoughts and acts that are against the teaching and rules of Islam it isn't prohibit or nor is it against Islam.