# Internet business in Islam

Tags: business, internet

I am going to start an online website in which users can post anything which is happened in their surroundings. Users are allowed to post 1 picture and a text. Please let me know whether this is a halaal or haram? What I need to take care?

Answer would be helpful for me to avoid my confusion if Allah wills.

Comment: Could you please redefine the last sentence, *"Answer would be avoid my confusion if allah wills."*. I can't tell what you are trying to say here.

Comment: I modified......can you answer to my question?

Comment: Since the scope of this question is too broad therefore I would answer the question in more or less the same generic manner as I did [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/10136/3487). You can ask multiple specific question about things you feel doubtful about though.

Comment: Am i responsible for the any user who posts which is haram? i will try by best but sometime if it happens am i responsible?

Comment: I'd consider going to a local Mufti. I am not sure posting or even taking pictures is allowed in Islam. If that's the case, then taking your case to a Mufti would be helpful instead of getting contradicting answers here.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice of running this type of website are

- There must be a EULA  which have terms about what users can post  and what not, here you can disallow posting haram, anti-Islam, anti-social things.
- No post should be published without review by the moderator/s.
- There must be an option of flagging the posts by visitors. So that site admin can review the posts.

If you take all these or more steps honestly to monitor/screen the content of your website. Then there is no harm in running this type of website.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.....Suppose there is a music concert and a user posted it.....Can i allow? Main intent of my website is affected if i am not allow.....please throw some light////

Comment: music/musical gatherings are haram.